# What happens after Unbricking a Oneplus 3

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, unbricking, bootloader, oneplus-3

There are many guide to unbrick the oneplus 3 and I followed the  [GUIDE] Mega Unbrick Guide for A Hard Bricked OnePlus 3 on xda by Naman Bhalla and after the step 9 this is my condition now
 i cannot access the recovery mode (but i can access the bootloader). when i try to access recovery mode a page appears that has its its first line as follows

start do md5 checksum.

then the below lines appear in red

cache : failed.
boot : failed.
boot_aging : failed.
system : failed.
md5 checksum failed.

when i try to upload oneplus stock rom through command window it says

archive does not contain 'android-info.txt'.
archive does not contain 'android-product.txt'.
error: update package has no android-info.txt or android-product.txt.

And one more thing ,I think i reached this glorious stage during a supersu unroot.WILL his lead to any more complications?

Please help. Being like this feels like forever. I am living in India so the chance of someone else knowing anything about this are very slim.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It seems like there's fail in the md5 checking, may be it's corrupted. Try download the file again. You may read this thread on how to return on stock firmware. http://www.technobuzz.net/return-to-100-stock-on-oneplus-3/

Comment: Which file should I download again? The thread mentioned tell me about how to return to stock firmware.But for that recovery mode must be accessed , which is not possible in my case.

Comment: So you need to flash the stock recovery then.

Comment: Go here http://www.technobuzz.net/oneplus-3-stock-recovery/

Comment: OK. But due to some reason ADB folder(C:\adb) is not created even when running he installer as administrator.

Comment: Download Minimal ADB and Fastboot (.exe if you're on Windows). It works fine, no need to set path,etc. Just install it an run it. put files inside the program's folder to flash them (right click on the icon in the desktop and choose "open the folder", or simply CD to the folder containing the files to be flashed

Comment: Check my updated answer to get Minimal ADB and Fastboot

Comment: OK , but how to flash it ?

Comment: I libked the tutorial on my answer

Comment: Great. Just now the whole phone went blank and it is not responding.I think it is because of low power but no low power indicator page is found when charging.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're able to connect to bootloader, you need to flah the stock recovery then flash the stock firmware. This [tutorial](http://www.technobuzz.net/oneplus-3-stock-recovery/) explains it better.

Go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) to get Minimal ADB and Fastboot. Open it and run commands. You must CD to the folder containing the files to be flashed. Exemple: `CD C:\Downloads\my_stock_firmware`
and tape commands from there.

Comment: But the stock recovery or twrp cannot be flashed

Comment: Do you get an error with the stock recovery also?

Comment: Yes  , I get an error with the stock recovery.

Comment: What exactly? please describe it

Comment: Nothing can be done now as the phone is not responding.

Comment: All this for nothing ,I guess

Comment: What did you exactly do? If your phone is not powering up due to battery low, charge it

Comment: My pc still recognizes my device as its driver signature is disabled.But i guess something must have happened to the screen

Comment: Nothing has happened to the display, just flash the stock firmware. Did you follow the tutorial?

Comment: I cannot flash the stock firmware as bootloader cannot be accessed

Comment: Do you mean your phone is not detected by Fastboot?

Comment: Yes the phone is not detected by fastboot

Comment: How do you boot in Fastboot mode?

Answer (score -1):

Same error here for me with my OnePlus 3.. "cache : failed. boot : failed. boot_aging : failed. system : failed. md5 checksum failed."

**EDIT:**

Resolved with this tutorial https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/updated-28-06-2016-mega-unbrick-guide-for-a-hard-bricked-oneplus-2.347607/